# tfjs Error: Argument tensors passed to stack must be a `Tensor[]` or `TensorLike[]`

Tags: lstm, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to build a simple deep lstm neural network. I'm not much experienced with machine learning in general. But I do know some basics. This is my sample model.

```js
const model    = tf.sequential();
const {layers} = tf;

model.add(layers.lstm({
    units           : 256,
    inputShape      : [1, 6],
    activation      : "relu",
    returnSequences : true,
}));
model.add(layers.dropout({rate: 0.2}));
model.add(layers.batchNormalization());

model.add(layers.lstm({
    units           : 128,
    activation      : "relu",
    returnSequences : true,
}));
model.add(layers.dropout({rate: 0.2}));
model.add(layers.batchNormalization());

model.add(layers.lstm({
    units      : 128,
    activation : "relu",
}));
model.add(layers.dropout({rate: 0.2}));
model.add(layers.batchNormalization());

model.add(layers.dense({
    units      : 32,
    activation : "relu",
}));
model.add(layers.dropout({rate: 0.2}));

model.add(layers.dense({
    units      : 2,
    activation : "softmax",
}));
model.compile({
    //loss      : "sparseCategoricalCrossentropy",
    loss      : "categoricalCrossentropy",
    optimizer : tf.train.adam(0.001),
    metrics   : ['acc']
});
```

And when I trying to train the model I got this error.

```js
const result = await model.fit(tf.ones([1, 1, 6]), tf.ones([1, 2]));

Error: Argument tensors passed to stack must be a `Tensor[]` or `TensorLike[]`
```

I found a [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3550) about bug on github. But I don't think this is `tfjs` bug. Because that thread was more than a year ago. If it was a bug I'm pretty sure google fixed already. I think I did something wrong here. Also I tried exact same model in python and it's working fine... But I don't want to use python. I quit python many years ago since nodejs came out. I love javascript more than python and which is much easier to me maintaining. Can you help me understand what is wrong here?

Comment: I had the same error. For me it was changing my lstm inputShape from [1, 20] to [20, 1]. See here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3550#issuecomment-906864211

Comment: Oh wow. In tensorflowjs inputShape dimension is reversed huh? It's interesting and also very confusing to compare python models... Anyway it's working now. Thank you very mych. :)

Comment: For me, if I put [1, x], even [1, 1] it's throwing that error. Also it runs a lot slower with this current solution. If it works in python, perhaps your encoding is different from js? Anyway, would love to see an actual solution to this.

Comment: @JanV.  Are you sure we can reverse inputShape? From my understanding, the first dimension is the timestep.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in tf.js namely RNN layers don't accept sequences with just one element (throws an error when fitting). From my understanding, when using stateful RNN, it might make sense to pass just one element at a time (correct me if I'm wrong).

As a temporal solution for testing, I simply repeat an input tensor before wiring it to the RNN layer. Theoretically, RNN should learn to ignore the repeated frame:

```js
outputs = tf.layers.flatten().apply(outputs)
outputs = tf.layers.repeatVector({n: 2}).apply(outputs)
outputs = tf.layers.gru({units: 32}).apply(outputs)
```

Also, I made a custom stateful GRU layer that can accept just one element (only for testing). However, I did not find much difference with repeating:

```js
class MyGruLayer extends tf.layers.Layer {
    constructor(args) {
        super(args)

        this.cell = new tf.layers.gruCell(args)
        this.states_ = null
        this.keptStates = []
    }

    build(inputShape) {
        this.cell.build(inputShape)
        this.resetStates()
        this.stateSpec = {shape: [null, this.cell.stateSize]}
        this.built = true
    }

    computeOutputShape(inputShape) {
        return [inputShape[0], this.cell.stateSize]
    }

    call(inputs, kwargs) {
        return tf.tidy(() => {
            const training = kwargs == null ? null : kwargs['training']
            const cellCallKwargs = {training}
            const input = inputs[0]
            const initialState= this.states_

            const [outputs, ...states] = this.cell.call([input].concat(initialState), cellCallKwargs)

            this.resetStates(states, training)

            return outputs
        })
    }
    
    /* Method from https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/tfjs-v3.12.0/tfjs-layers/src/layers/recurrent.ts#L562 */
    resetStates(states, training = false) {
        tf.tidy(() => {
            if (this.states_ == null) {
                if (Array.isArray(this.cell.stateSize)) {
                    this.states_ = this.cell.stateSize.map(dim => tf.zeros([batchSize, dim]));
                } else {
                    this.states_ = [tf.zeros([batchSize, this.cell.stateSize])];
                }
            } else if (states == null) {
                // Dispose old state tensors.
                tf.dispose(this.states_);
                // For stateful RNNs, fully dispose kept old states.
                if (this.keptStates != null) {
                    tf.dispose(this.keptStates);
                    this.keptStates = [];
                }
        
                if (Array.isArray(this.cell.stateSize)) {
                    this.states_ = this.cell.stateSize.map(dim => tf.zeros([batchSize, dim]));
                } else {
                    this.states_[0] = tf.zeros([batchSize, this.cell.stateSize]);
                }
            } else {
                if (training === true) {
                  this.keptStates.push(this.states_.slice());
                } else {
                  tf.dispose(this.states_);
                }
        
                for (let index = 0; index < this.states_.length; ++index) {
                  const value = states[index];
                  const dim = Array.isArray(this.cell.stateSize) ?
                      this.cell.stateSize[index] :
                      this.cell.stateSize;
                  const expectedShape = [batchSize, dim];
                  if (value.shape[0] != batchSize || value.shape[1] != dim) {
                    throw new Error(
                        `State ${index} is incompatible with layer ${this.name}: ` +
                        `expected shape=${expectedShape}, received shape=${
                            value.shape}`);
                  }
                  this.states_[index] = value;
                }
            }

            this.states_ = this.states_.map(state => tf.keep(state.clone()));
        })
    }

    static get className() {
        return 'MyGruLayer';
    }
}

tf.serialization.registerClass(MyGruLayer)

// Example: outputs = new MyGruLayer({units: 32}).apply(outputs)
```